# three.js component wont be displayed in my html page

Tags: html, three.js, webgl

I've been trying to integrate three.js to my html project
[19:48]
html code for the canvas
[image]

js code

[image]

I get this error :(( and the cube is not displayed
[image]

Please help me out

Comment: Please do never share screenshots from your code. Instead, please reproduce the issue with a live example like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735159/three-js-geometry-isnt-showing-in-browser-but-the-scene-is/69735345

Comment: As Mugen87 said, please provide actual code. When you construct WebGLRenderer you either pass in a canvas element or Three.js creates one for you and returns it as domElement. In your code you are doing both. You should remove the appendChild code because your canvas is already on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think three.js creates it's own canvas. Try querying for the containing element instead.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("#orangeDiv");
```